# T-SQL : how should this SQL query checking date conditions be generalized (instead of hard coded)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given the table USERLOGINS:

```
rowid|userID|logindate          |
-----+------+-------------------+
    1|     1|2018-12-28 00:00:00|
    2|     2|2019-01-03 00:00:00|
    3|     1|2019-02-25 00:00:00|
    4|     3|2019-03-02 00:00:00|
    5|     2|2019-03-04 00:00:00|
    6|     1|2019-05-29 00:00:00|
    7|     1|2019-09-09 00:00:00|
    8|     2|2019-07-07 00:00:00|
    9|     3|2019-08-08 00:00:00|
   10|     1|2019-11-28 00:00:00|
```

To retrieve the `userid` for which there's at least one login in every quarter of the last year (by removing a year, considering the current date), one could hardcode it to check every condition, with something as such:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userID
FROM USERLOGINS 
GROUP BY userID 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN logindate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE())  
                                   AND DATEADD(MONTH, -12 + 3, GETDATE())     
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 
           END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN logindate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12 + 3, GETDATE())  
                                   AND DATEADD(MONTH, -12 + 6, GETDATE())
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 
           END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN logindate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12 + 6, GETDATE())   
                                   AND DATEADD(MONTH, -12 + 9, GETDATE())
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 
           END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN logindate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12 + 9, GETDATE())  
                                   AND GETDATE()          
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 
           END) > 0;
```

[The desired output is the `userid` 1]

However this quickly becomes unmanageable (say, trying to achieve the same but checking for every month over a period of five years). What would be a practical way to generalize the checks instead of hardcoding them all?

Comment: So you simply want to check if a user logged in at least once, in every quarter? Do you have a Calendar Table?

Comment: When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than getting an exact [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) (or `SUM`) and then just checking if it is greater than zero.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, the goal is to check if there is at least one login every quarter. The only table I have is the one presented in the example. The accepted answer seems to solve the case pretty potently. Apologies for the time to check back on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just check if there are 4 distinct quarters in the last year for the user.

```
-- users with a login in 4 quarters within year
SELECT userID
FROM USERLOGINS 
WHERE logindate > CAST(DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) AS DATE)
GROUP BY userID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATEPART(quarter, logindate)) = 4;
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/GHGP66760)

Answer (score 0):

```
        ;With CTE as (

        SELECT DISTINCT userID AS userID,
                DATEADD(quarter,DATEDIFF(quarter,0,logindate),0) as logindate
        FROM   USERLOGINS AS om
        GROUP BY
                DATEADD(quarter,DATEDIFF(quarter,0,logindate),0),logindate
    )
    select
        userID,
        DATEPART(year,logindate) -
           CASE WHEN DATEPART(quarter,logindate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as FinancialYear,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(quarter,logindate) = 1 THEN 4
           ELSE DATEPART(quarter,logindate) - 1 END as FinancialQuarter
    from
        CTE 
   ORDER BY FinancialYear,FinancialQuarter ASC
```

You will get the Data every wise with(Column Name as '**FinancialYear**') and Four quarter every year has (Column Name as '**FinancialQuarter**')

Here i'm using dateadd in sql server...for more info about dateadd refer this link...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This doesn't seem to (at least by itself) solve what was intended, as it isn't filtering out the `userID` based on the criteria, but instead fitting every date in a year/quarter; Although it doesn't seem complicated to take it from here, the accepted answer solves the issue directly instead.